# Iterating through array using loop in c++ and program says "exit status -1"?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, exit, status

So I am trying to get comfortable with arrays for my HW assignments. I have two loops. First loop iterates through the sequence, that's good and well I think I dont know. Then the second loop is supposed to display all inputs the user inputted depending on how big size_of_array is (in this case, it's 5, so that should be 5 cars the user enters).

When i run it, the first part works just fine in terms of taking input, but the second part F R E A K S out and gives me "exit status -1" wtf?!?!?!??!

Appreciate the help:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int size_of_array = 5;
  string ideal_cars[size_of_array];
  int count;

  for (count = 1; count <= size_of_array; count++)
  {
    cout << "Enter car number " << count << "." << "\n";
    cin >> ideal_cars[count];
  }

  for (count = 0; count <= size_of_array; count++)
  {
    cout << "You entered " << ideal_cars[count] << ".";
  }


}
```

Comment: You're running past the end of the array. In both loops, you want to start from 0 and go to `count < size_of_array`.

Comment: Your code does not show a return from main of an int value ... undefined behavior ?  Maybe try "return 0;" at end of main.

Comment: @JerryCoffin what do you mean? can you give more explanation/insight by what you mean by "end of array"? I thought I was just going from 0 to 5 i don't understand!! thanks for help so far man

Comment: @2785528 `main` does not require a return statement in C++.

Comment: @ShahJacob You go from 1 to 5, inclusive, but your array's indices go from 0 to 4, inclusive. That's because an array's index is a _distance from the start_, not the _position of an element_. So, the first element is at index 0 because it's zero elements away from the beginning.

Comment: why do you know it goes from 1 to 5? are you saying my for loop goes through index 0 to 4? i'm not sure by what you mean

Comment: First, `count = 1` means it starts at 1. Then, `count <= size_of_array` means it won't exit until the count is bigger than 5, which means the last value of `count` in that loop will be 5.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel what does that have to do with array indices being 0 to 4? like what is the problem causing the program to fail here??

Comment: For an array with length 5, the valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. If you access an element at index 5, you're going out of bounds of the array, which invokes _undefined behaviour_. In your case that means a crash, but it could also silently appear to work and break everything else in the program.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel okay that makes perfect sense, thank you. but what did you mean by "That's because an array's index is a distance from the start, not the position of an element."?

Comment: The index is the number of elements between the one you want and the start of the array. So, `array[0]` has no elements before it, `array[1]` as one, `array[2]` as two, etc. That's why `array[5]` is out of bounds in an array of 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The first index of an array is 0, so when `size_of_array` is 5, the possible indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

- The 1st element is `ideal_cars[0]`.
- The 2nd element is `ideal_cars[1]`.
- The 3rd element is `ideal_cars[2]`.
- The 4th element is `ideal_cars[3]`.
- The 5th element is `ideal_cars[4]`.

`ideal_cars[5]` is out of range and not allowed. For a graphical illustration, see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays.

So in your for loop you need to make sure `count` is less and not equal to `size_of_array`:

```
for (count = 0; count < size_of_array; count++)
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int size_of_array = 5;
  string ideal_cars[size_of_array];
  int count;

  for (count = 0; count < size_of_array; count++)
  {
    cout << "Enter car number " << count << "." << endl;
    cin >> ideal_cars[count];
  }

  for (count = 0; count < size_of_array; count++)
  {
    cout << "You entered " << ideal_cars[count] << "." << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/LWbSeu.

Comment: Please clarify some more? Sorry just started coding... I'm really confused annd appreciate more explanation. Could you give some more context as to what you mean? Why does what you do work instead of mine?

Comment: Added explanations.

Comment: why is ideal_cars[5] out of range? When you mean out of range do you mean for the array? Also is my array starts at 0 then shouldn't it be 0 1 2 3 4? That's 5 positions? So why would it be out of range if I'm counting 5 elements? I'm really confused. The textbook code looks the SAME and works fine

Comment: When you declare `string ideal_cars[5];` you're creating an array with 5 elements. These 5 elements can be accessed with `ideal_cars[0]`, `ideal_cars[1]`, `ideal_cars[2]`, `ideal_cars[3]`, `ideal_cars[4]`. Then `ideal_cars[5]` is the 6th element right? Note you only use `string ideal_cars[5]` to **declare** the array, and `ideal_cars[0..4]` to **use** the array.